# Basic algebra question. Find W in a system with 3 other unkowns and 2 equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I suspect this is a ratter dumb question, but I just want to be sure. I need to find W in the following equation:
$$W=\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{6}{5}y+\frac{2}{7}z$$
And the only thing I know is:
$$5=3x+6y+2z$$

Of course this a simplification of the real problem, but is it possible to find W?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the real problem if I may ask?

Comment: Suppose that $(x,y,z)=(1,0,1)$, then $W=\frac{25}{14}$.  Suppose that $(x,y,z)=(-1,1,1)$, then $W=-\frac{1}{70}$.  Your question does not have a unique answer.

Comment: There is a portfolio of 100+ stocks, weighted by market cap. The beta of the portfolio can be accurately estimated, but not the betas of the individual stocks.
We know that beta of the portfolio is a weighted average (by market cap) of the unknown betas of the component stocks.
W would be the unlevered beta of the portofolio, which is the weighted average of the unlevered betas of the stocks, which are the unknown betas of the stocks divided by a factor that is known for each company (based on Hamada's equation)

Michael: that's what I thought :/ Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for example the second equation is satisfied by both $$(x,y,z)=(1,1,-2)$$ and $$(x,y,z)=(0,1,-\frac{1}{2})$$ but both yield different results for $W$.
So you need more information to find $W$. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you have what's called an [undetermined system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system) - since you have 2 equations with 4 unknown variables you cannot find a single solution to $W$.

What you can do is remove one of the variables by solving for that variable in the second equation and substituting it into the first equation:

$$
x=\frac{5}{3}-2y-\frac{2}{3}z \\
W=\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{5}{3}-2y-\frac{2}{3}z\right)+\frac{6}{5}y+\frac{2}{7}z=
\frac{5}{2}-\frac{9}{5}y-\frac{5}{7}z
$$

Here, your solution to $W$ is more like a function of two variables, $y$ and $z$, so if you can get values for $y$ and $z$ or get two more equations, then you can solve for $W$.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful